# How to remove padding from last generated DIV on a page

Tags: css, html, margin

I have an ExpressionEngine installation which generates a DIV for each person's bio on the contact page. I have the margin-bottom set to 20px for these DIVs that are generated but I want the last DIV to have 0px margin on the bottom so that there is the same amount of space between the bottom of the last div and the bottom of the container as there is at the top of the first DIV. I know you can use something like `:nth-child` for P and LI elements, but I'm wondering if there is a similar way to do this with an entire div. This is the code I am using:

```
{people}
    <div class="bio mobile-inner">
        <img class="grid_4_desktop grid_4_tablet grid_1_mobile" width="216" height="auto" title="" src="{image}" />
        <div class="grid_12_desktop grid_8_tablet grid_1_mobile leader-info">
            <h3>{name}</h3>
            <h5>{title}</h5>
            <p>{bio}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{/people}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this :

```
div.bio:last-child {
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/Z7Whb/1/**

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing which element has the margin, it is difficult to tell, however this should solve it, assuming the `.bio` element has `margin-bottom`, you would use:

```
.bio:last-child {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

You might need to be a little more specific in the selector to ensure that it will overwrite the initial declaration. Also, make sure this declartion is appearing after the initial one in the stylesheet, as it is read from top to bottom. Thus you don't want it to be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

```
#your_parent_container div:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0; 
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YFL3A/)

Comment: You should probably replace the generic `div` with the class name, as there may be other `div` elements following it.

Comment: That wouldn't work. Last of type doesn't work with class names. Element types only. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YFL3A/1/

Comment: `:last-child` only works if the element is the LAST CHILD of its parent, so `.bio:last-child` also wouldn't work if there was another div after the last `.bio`. Seems illogical to me that there isn't a `:last-of-class` selector